# What is the best and most used way of wiring in spring dependency injection

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

This question is not pure coding but pre coding.
Actually I am new to spring in winter season. I have a question is that What is the best and most used way of wiring in spring dependency injection? I come to know that xml based wiring is old now. I have confusion between annotation and java-based autowiring. I didn't get enough evidence to choose the right one. Which is most used way now a days? or I have to learn all(which might be confusing at some point).

Comment: Wiring options include xml, annotations, java, and groovy. They all have their own strengths and there is no clear winner. Voting to close as opinion-based.

Comment: ya nathan, still they are running on the track and yet to touch the red ribbon. But I want to know how is more ahead now?

Comment: sorry, polls and popularity contests are off-topic here.

Comment: @ Nathan Hughes: can you tell me the reason for downvoted the question? it may sound a foolish question to you but I have that doubt. If you dont want/know to give ans then simply ignore, others are there to give the ans to the "foolish" question as I got my doubt cleared maximum.

Comment: I said "off-topic", not foolish. It's not a foolish question, it's just not something this site handles, because there's no right technical answer. just pick one and learn it well. If you are interviewing nobody will blame you for knowing a different method than what their project uses.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would say that in most of cases, you won't need Java based auto wiring( i assume you are referring here to java based config).
However, they will be specific situations when you will need to programmatically locate beans and play with context objects. 
As a start you can use auto wiring till you get a better understanding of Spring framework life cycle.

Comment: Needless to say that by the end of the  day, the 2 ways serve the same purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Autowiring is just nothing just like create an object of that type.

```
@Autowired
Person person;
```

Here autowire create an object of person type just like EJB

```
@EJB
EntityManager em;
```

You can done Dependency Injection by constructor invoking or by using setter getter method.

```
public class Person{
  private String userName;
  private String email;
  //constructor invoking
  public Person(String userName,String email){
      this.userName= userName;
      this.email = email;
  }

  //setter and getter based 
  public String getUserName(){
     return userName;
  }
  public String getEmail(){
     return email;
  }
  public void setUserName(String userName){
     this.userName = userName;
  }

  public void setEmail(String email){
     this.email = email;
  }
}
```

It totally depends on you in which type of dependency injection suits your problem.
You can [read it](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_autowired_annotation.htm) for better explanation.